# Can some one please explain why Cassandra writes are faster than postgres

Tags: postgresql, cassandra

Can some one please explain the cases why Cassandra's wites fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Cassandra uses log-structured merge trees for storing,which means all writes are done sequentially (the database is the append-only
>   log), which results in lower write latency.
>
> 2.Key space such that each machine is only responsible for a portion of the keys, so the key search space per node is less.
>
> 3.Cassandra, any replica can initiate a write , it is not necessary that only master node has to initiate writes. This is faster as there
>   won't be any write time wait for master nomination.
>
> 4.Cassandra log writing is faster because it completely eliminates searching process before writing the log.